# How to send a file (e.g image or text file) to specific ip address in python

Tags: python, python-2.7

I tried to use 'requests' library for sending the data, 
but without success

```
      import requests
        file_name = "s_shot"
        app = wx.App()
        screen = wx.ScreenDC()
        size = screen.GetSize()
        bmp = wx.EmptyBitmap(size[0], size[1])
        mem = wx.MemoryDC(bmp)
        mem.Blit(0,0,size[0], size[1], screen, 0, 0)
        del mem

        # capture screen and save it to file
        my_file = '{}{}{}'.format(file_name,i,'.png')
        bmp.SaveFile(my_file, wx.BITMAP_TYPE_PNG)
        i+=1
        url = '127.0.0.1:30000/file'
        files = {'media': open(my_file, 'rb')}
        requests.post(url, files=files)
```

but it shows me the error:

```
raise MissingSchema("Invalid URL %r: No schema supplied" % url)
requests.exceptions.MissingSchema: Invalid URL u'127.0.0.1:30000/file': No schema supplied
```

Comment: Did you try `http://127.0.0.1:3000`?

Comment: yes, it shows me :               requests.exceptions.ConnectionError: HTTPConnectionPool(host='127.0.0.1', port=3000): Max retries exceeded with url: /file (Caused by <class 'socket.error'>: [Errno 10061] No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it)

Comment: So... I assume you're not running an HTTP server on port 3000?

Comment: to do that, am i supposed to create a http server that'll listen to port 3000,for example, use node.js to do it? and it'll wait for the python requests. I don't understand ..

Comment: ok i opened the http server but it showed me it : HTTP connection (1): 127.0.0.1 Setting read timeout to None "POST /file HTTP/1.1" 200 None  ,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If  your motto is to send file only, you can do it simply by running python Simple Server on your machine and making the client to download it  through the Browser.

python 2.7 comes with a built-in light weight server.

You can launch it with `python -m SimpleHTTPServer 80`. This will launch the server on port 80.